# PDF file sent from flask to client is empty when downloaded

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask, axios

I have a flask server that sends a pdf file with the send_file function.
When I test this route on postman I can view and download the pdf.
However when I try to download it through my React frontend the file is blank BUT with the correct amount of pages.
I suppose the problem stems from my use of blob but I don't see how.

Server route

```
@app.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
def results():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return send_file("pdf-path", cache_timeout=0, as_attachment=True)
```

This route works fine when tested on postman. I can view the pdf

client side

```
axios.get(URL + '/test')
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            const type = 'application/pdf';
            const file = new Blob([response.data], { type: type });
            saveAs(file, "test.pdf");
        }
    }
    )
```

Here I am using axios and file-saver.
The file is downloaded but all the pages are empty.

Comment: What is `data` in your client-side code? Also note that you don't have to do any of this; you can simply do `location = URL + '/test';` to start the download.

Comment: @ChrisG changed data to response.data in the question.
This worked! But I'm still curious as to why my method isn't working

Comment: What do you mean, "your method"? Using `data` without declaring it should yield a reference error.

Comment: @ChrisG that was a typo. It is response.data

Comment: Ok, so by "this worked" you mean `location = URL + '/test';`? Not sure why the Blob method failed, what do you get when you log `response.data`? Is it a Buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
from flask import send_file, send_from_directory
@app.route('/uploads/<path:filename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def download(filename):
    uploads = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'uploads') # uploads is a folder
    return send_from_directory(directory=uploads, filename=filename)
```

send_from_directory - Most recommended method.

If you want to use send_file method,

```
@app.route("/get-csv/<path:filename>")
def get_csv(filename):

    safe_path = safe_join(app.config["CLIENT_CSV"], filename)

    try:
        return send_file(safe_path, as_attachment=True)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        abort(404)
```